# Adding Vehicles to Delivery Outposts

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, analytics, shortest-path

This is a hypothetical optimization question that I'm trying to answer through programming.

Say that company A is a pizza delivery company that has five outposts that have different number of delivery motorcycles. It just bought two additional motorcycles. How does it optimally place these two additional resources to maximally reduce the overall delivery time.

These outposts may have overlapping delivery zones where any of the outposts may deliver to.

The data that is available looks like this:

```
Outpost No | Resource No | Location of Outpost | Delivery Destination | Delivery Start Time | Delivery Duration
```

The solution that I have in mind is this: Take the total delivery duration for each outpost, and give the two additional motorcycles to the two busiest outposts (as determined by greatest total delivery duration).

Are there any well-known methods to solve such problems? If so, please give links to the necessary resources to do so.

Comment: @akrun Can you please explain to me what you mean by reproducible example? My expected output is the most optimal location(s) to put the additional motorbikes in terms of delivery times.